# Как повесить событие на элементы, загруженные средствами AJAX?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть кусок кода `http://jsfiddle.net/aboob5s7/`, который по клику подгружает `html` через `$.get`.
Каким образом после загрузки повесить событие на элементы с классом `.reader`?

Comment: пове**с**ить, oh my

Comment: подробнеей можно?

Comment: @Mihan, а что ж подробней вы хотите услышать? @Etki против повешений, он за расстрел. )) А вообще, вам нужна делегированная обработка событий. Облом повторять одно и тоже, поэтому [читайте в прошлых ответах][1].

   [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/375834#375873

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".reader").live("click", function(){
  ...
});
```

С jQuery-1.7, данный метод считается устаревшим, поэтому **live** советуют заменять на **on**, тогда:

```
$(document).on("click", ".reader", function(){ 
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$( ".reader" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert('Заработало!');
});
```